# querying and mutating firebase realtime database many to many (two way) relationships

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I have been going over the docs
https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write
and quite a few examples online. But here's the disconnect: None of them seem to account for the randomly generated id from firebase when adding an object to the db.

Based on my research, flattened data is the way to go. So I have structured my data:

[image]

But when adding a player, for example:

- how do I not only add him to the players object, but also to the
  team_memberships object?
- and how then, does the teams object know how to reference
  the player and where to do so?

Here is my client-side code (JavaScript (Vue + Typescript)):

```
addPlayer({ state }, payload) {
    const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (user) {
      firebase
        .database()
        .ref('users').child(user.uid).child('players')
        .push({
          firstName: payload.firstName,
          lastName: payload.lastName,
          jerseyNumber: payload.jerseyNumber,
          teamName: payload.teamName
        });
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`update()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update) method which allows writing "multiple values to the Database at once" (see also [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)):

Here is an example on how you would do for the first case ("how do I not only add him to the players object, but also to the team_memberships object").

```
var userObj = {
    firstName: payload.firstName,
    lastName: payload.lastName,
    jerseyNumber: payload.jerseyNumber,
    teamName: payload.teamName
};

var team_id = '....'  //I don't know how you plan to get this value.

var newPlayerKey = firebase.database().ref('users').child(user.uid).child('players').push().key;

var updates = {};
updates['/users/' + user.uid + '/players/' + newPlayerKey] = userObj;
updates['/users/' + user.uid + '/team_memberships/' + team_id + '/' + newPlayerKey] = true;

return firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
```

Note: I don't know how you plan to get the value of `team_id` but most probably from the front end, since you have the `teamName`.

Comment: @Khepf Hi, did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: I just got back to it today and it is just what I had in mind, thank you!!!